# Facebook Events Buy Now with ticket_uri

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Looks like Facebook has added a new field that you can have a button show up on the Facebook event where people can purchase tickets. I tried to add it to a existing event but just called calling the below which just returns "1" so it appears it works but I don't see a buy now button appearing anywhere. Anyone have any thoughts?

[access_token] => {mytoken}
[ticket_uri] => {ticketurl}

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Comment: Is it an event owned/created by a Page? From the docs: Note: ticket_uri is only available to events created by page admins on events that are created for pages.

Comment: Yes it was created by a page. Here is an example of an event = http://www.facebook.com/events/417081971696223/

Comment: Then we need to see your code to help.

Answer (score 0):

That event was created on the old events backend, so it won't support the ticket_uri field. You need to go to your Advanced Settings and enable the "Events Timezone" migration, which will move you to the new events backend. Events created from that point on will properly support the ticket_uri field.

Comment: Is there anyway to add the link to an event that was created under the old system? We are rolling this feature out to our clients which have thousands of events in existence. Are those event just outta luck, or is there some sort of update-event-to-use-the-new-timezone-goodness graph api function?

Comment: I went in and enabled the Events Timezone migration in the Facebook App but it still isn't posting the Buy Now. Below are the fields I am posting

[access_token] =>""
[privacy_type] => ""
[host] => ""
[name] => ""
[start_time] => ""
[end_time] => ""
[location_id] => ""
[location] => ""
[street] => ""
[city] => ""
[state] => ""
[zip] => ""
[description] => ""
[ticket_uri] => ""
[photo] => ""

Answer (score 0):

You must get a "Page access token" and then post to {page_id}/events. Here's a copy of the steps I've posted a couple of places:

1. Enable the "Events Timezone migration"
2. Log into FB as a user that has admin rights on the FB Page that we want events posted to
3. Use the APPLICATION's ID to build this link to authorize the
   managing of pages
   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=MY_SITE_URL&scope=manage_pages,create_event&response_type=token
4. Exchange token for perm (longer token)
   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY_APP_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=(token from step 3)
5. Visit this page, find the PAGE you want to post and copy the new
   access_token https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=
   (token from step 4)
6. Use this last token (from step 5) and the PAGE's ID to post to post
   the event per the instructions at
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#events

Note that if you create a lot of events, you will "spam" every user who Like'd the page. FB recently added the 'no_feed_story' option to prevent this.

Comment: You should not post the same answer on multiple questions. If the questions are truly the same, answer one of them and then flag the other as a duplicate.

Comment: You're right, and I generally don't. In this case, I felt that the questions were not exactly the same but the answer was applicable to both.

Comment: Ok; I don't know enough about the subject area to do anything besides leave a comment, as I did, but be aware that identical answers are automatically flagged by the system and shown to 10k users reviewing posts. So don't be surprised if you get more emphatic "feedback" down the road. :)